# How to create a page without layout in Angular SPA?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to create a SPA. I need to have a login page which will have only Username & password field. All other pages will have header & footer sections in common. I am keeping the header & footer section in _layout.html page & using ng-view to render main content. As a result Layout content is coming for login page also.

So in _layout.html page I am using ng-show, ng-hide based on existance of authenticated user.

```
<div ng-controller="layoutController as lc">
    // for login
    <div ng-hide="lc.isAuthenticated">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
    // for all pages but login
    <div id="wrap" class="equipment" ng-show="lc.isAuthenticated">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                // content here
            </div>

            <div class="main-container">
                <div ng-view></div>                    
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-10">
                    <ul class="">
                        <li>CRE: </li>
                        <li>Machine Count: <span>35</span></li>
                        <li>Data Date: <span>N/A</span></li>
                        <li>User: <span>bla bla</span></li>
                        <li>Company: <span>bla bla</span></li>
                        <li>Subscription Expiry: <span>05/31/2016</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

After login when I am redirecting to a page, using

```
 $location.path("dashboard")
```

it's not loading _layout again & hence layout content is not coming. What's the correct way to achieve this.
How to restrict some pages from using layout or how to make layout page reload after successful login?

Comment: are you changing `lc.isAuthenticated` to true?

Comment: yes
after login I am setting this value to true. I am doing 
lc.isAuthenticated = authenticateService.isAuthenticated in layoutController & setting authenticateService.isAuthenticated = true after login in authenticateService.